# text field focus swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, focus, textfield

I have word  for example "Hello [friend]".
I take symbols what inside  brackets "[]" and change them to textFields.
and I need to make focus for it, when screen appear focus should be on first textField. and if user input correct symbol - move to next textfield, if wrong - stay.

here is my code, and I tried to make index, but I user forEach, for make text fields, so i have problem with focus, and focus stay on last textField. how to make logic what I described here?

```
  import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class LetterViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isCorrect: Bool = false
    @Published var enteredText: String = ""
    @Published var storedLetters: [String] = []
    @Published var backgroundColor: Color = .clear
    @Published var textColor: Color = .black
}

struct LetterView: View {
    let letter: Character
    let isBlank: Bool
    @Binding var enteredText: String
    @Binding var isCorrect: Bool
    let expectedCharacter: Character
    let startIndex: Int
    let totalFieldsCount: Int
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: LetterViewModel = LetterViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        let adjustedIndex = startIndex

        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            if isBlank {
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    CustomTextField(text: $viewModel.enteredText,
                                    expectedCharacter: expectedCharacter,
                                    isCorrectBinding: $viewModel.isCorrect,
                                    onTextChanged: { newText in
                                        self.viewModel.enteredText = newText
                                    },
                                    isCorrectChanged: { isCorrect in
                                        self.viewModel.isCorrect = isCorrect
                                        let textColor: Color = .black
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            self.viewModel.textColor = textColor
                                        }
                                        let backgroundColor = self.viewModel.enteredText.isEmpty ? Color.clear : (isCorrect ? Color.green.opacity(0.3) : Color.red.opacity(0.3))
                                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
                                            self.viewModel.backgroundColor = .clear
                                            if self.viewModel.isCorrect == false {
                                                self.viewModel.enteredText = ""
                                                self.viewModel.textColor = .clear
                                            }
                                        }
                                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                            self.viewModel.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
                                        }
                                    }, viewModel: viewModel)
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 30)
                        .background(self.viewModel.backgroundColor)
                        .foregroundColor(self.viewModel.textColor)
                        .focused($isFocused, equals: adjustedIndex == startIndex)
                        .onAppear {
                            if adjustedIndex == startIndex {
                                isFocused = true
                            }
                            print("adjustedIndex: \(adjustedIndex)")
                            print("startIndex: \(startIndex)")
                            print("-----------------------------------")
                        }

                }
            } else {
                Text(letter == " " ? " " : String(letter))
                    .foregroundColor(isCorrect ? .green : .black)
                    .fontWeight(isCorrect ? .bold : .regular)
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 4)
        .onReceive(viewModel.$isCorrect) { _ in
            if self.viewModel.isCorrect {
                let nextIndex = adjustedIndex + 1
                if nextIndex < totalFieldsCount {
                   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    let expectedCharacter: Character
    let isCorrectBinding: Binding<Bool>
    let onTextChanged: (String) -> Void
    let isCorrectChanged: (Bool) -> Void
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: LetterViewModel
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: CustomTextField

        init(parent: CustomTextField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            guard let newText = textField.text,
                  let textRange = Range(range, in: newText) else {
                return false
            }
            
            let updatedText = newText.replacingCharacters(in: textRange, with: string)
            
            if updatedText.count == 1 {
                self.parent.text = updatedText.lowercased()
                let isCorrect = (updatedText.lowercased() == String(self.parent.expectedCharacter).lowercased())
                self.parent.isCorrectBinding.wrappedValue = isCorrect
                self.parent.onTextChanged(updatedText)
                self.parent.isCorrectChanged(isCorrect)
            }
            return updatedText.count <= 1
        }
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.placeholder = "_"
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        textField.autocapitalizationType = .none
        textField.autocorrectionType = .no
        textField.keyboardType = .alphabet
        textField.textAlignment = .center
        textField.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        textField.backgroundColor = .clear
        textField.borderStyle = .none

        
        return textField
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.textColor = UIColor(self.viewModel.textColor)
    }
}

struct QuestionView: View {
    @Binding var titleText: String
    @Binding var skipButtonTitle: String
    @Binding var textFieldText: String
    var correctAnswer: String
    var skipTapped: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        let parsedCorrectAnswer = parseCorrectAnswer(correctAnswer)
        let answerLetters = takeLetters(correctAnswer)

        return VStack {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("\(titleText)")
                        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .medium))
                    Spacer()
                }
                .padding([.leading, .trailing], 16)
            }

            HStack(spacing: 5) {
                ForEach(0..<answerLetters.count, id: \.self) { index in
                    let expectedCharacter = parsedCorrectAnswer[index]
                    let isBlank = expectedCharacter == "_"
                    let adjustedIndex = index
                    let letterView = LetterView(
                        letter: expectedCharacter,
                        isBlank: isBlank,
                        enteredText: $textFieldText,
                        isCorrect: .constant(false),
                        expectedCharacter: answerLetters[index],
                        startIndex: adjustedIndex,
                        totalFieldsCount:  answerLetters.count
                    )
                    Group {
                        letterView
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                skipTapped()
            }) {
                Text("\(skipButtonTitle)")
                    .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .light))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            }
            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 12)
        }
    }
    
    private func parseCorrectAnswer(_ correctAnswer: String) -> [Character] {
        var result: [Character] = []
        var isInsideBrackets = false

        for char in correctAnswer {
            if char == "[" {
                isInsideBrackets = true
            } else if char == "]" {
                isInsideBrackets = false
            } else {
                if isInsideBrackets {
                    result.append("_")
                } else {
                    result.append(char)
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
    
    private func takeLetters(_ word: String) -> [Character] {
        var result: [Character] = []
        var isInsideBrackets = false

        for char in word {
            if char == "[" {
                isInsideBrackets = true
            } else if char == "]" {
                isInsideBrackets = false
            } else {
                if isInsideBrackets {
                    result.append(char)
                } else {
                    result.append("_")
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

and also, these words will be different and the brackets "[]" can be in different places. like "He[ll]o fr[ie]nd" or something like that. that is, I need to know how many textfields I have, as well as which one is the first, and focus on it, and then move it if the entered character is correct.

Comment: I am afraid you have shown too many lines of code without explaining their relevance.  What does the following mean?  "I need to make focus for it, when screen appear focus should be on first textField"